# Django materialize

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, materialize

So I have in my `forms.py`:

```
 auto_current_type = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label="Авто:", queryset=Auto_current_type.objects.all(),
                                                       widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

My template:

```
<div class="row">

    <form class="col s6 offset-s3 l6 offset-l3 m6 offset-m3" method="post">

        {% form %}

        {% endform %}

     <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Поиск
  </button>
    </form>
     </div>
```

But there how it looks like:
[image]

As you can see there is name of the car types, and below you can see checkboxes with the same names of the car types. But checkboxes are not working. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution
[here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-materialize-form/0.1.1)

I have just added `{{ form|materialize }}` and it started working